# Extract Regex Value in Excel Visual basic

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I have a Visual Basic code ready but it extracts everything but the matching regex.

[image: The sheet looks like this]

Here's the code I use:

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim strOutput As String

strPattern = "[a-zA-Z]{4}\d{4}$"

If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = Myrange.Value
    strReplace = ""
    
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = strPattern
    End With
    
    If regEx.test(strInput) Then
        simpleCellRegex = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)
    Else
        simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
    End If
End If
End Function
```

I use Excel 2019 on Windows.

Comment: If you want to get the matched string instead of what's left, don't use `.Replace()`. You need `regEx.Execute()` instead. You don't need `strReplace` and you don't need to set `Global` to True. Just use `simpleCellRegex = regEx.Execute(strInput)(0)`.

Comment: The code is replacing a matched string with "". But nothing is updated after this replacement. The 2 possible responses are: "" or "Not matched". But as the title mentions, you perhaps want to extract every matched strings. Please clarify what is expected to get after running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VBA**:

You could still do this via regex replace adjusting your pattern, but rather pull the value directly from the matchobject, for example:

```
Function simpleCellRegex(s As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "(?:^|\s)([a-zA-Z]{4}\d{4})$"
    If .Test(s) Then
        simpleCellRegex = .Execute(s)(0).submatches(0)
    Else
        simpleCellRegex = "No Match"
    End If
End With

End Function
```

You'll notice I edited the pattern to `(?:^|\s)([a-zA-Z]{4}\d{4})$`. This would ensure that the previous character is either non-existing *or* is a whitespace. This should prevent possible false positives when string is part of a larger substring. Even word-boundaries won't help in case of 'test-abcd1000'. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZg2NR/1). This does, however, require us to acces the submatches from the matchobject. Both indexes are zero-based. Another option is to use `Trim(.Execute(s)(0))` to get rid of the potential whitespace.

---

**FILTERXML()**:

Though regex is a viable option, it does require your workbook to be macro-enabled. You could opt for pattern validation with native function, for example `FILTERXML()`:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2;" ";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s[last()][translate(substring(.,1,4), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')=''][string-length()=8][substring(.,5)*0=0]");"No Match")
```

The meaning of the xpath used:

- `//s[last()]` - Get last element in array. In regex term; validate we are looking at the text before the end-line anchor;
- `[translate(substring(.,1,4), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')='']` - When first four characters are translated (alpha to empty string) check if remainder equals empty;
- `[string-length()=8]` - Check if lenght of string is 8 characters;
- `[substring(.,5)*0=0]` - Check that substring from 5th characters onwards equals zero when multiplied by zero.

---

[image]